# Eas build web support

Tags: expo, eas

Is it possible to build web version using `eas-cli build` command? I'm using `eas.json` file to manage different environment configurations, and I'm using iOS, Android & web versions, but for the moment I keep building the web using `expo build`, so the environments are always the same...

How can I manage the eas build for web?

Comment: Did you founded the answert?

Comment: So instead of expo build:web I'm using `expo export:web` now.
FYI: https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites